# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings

Tags: facebook, authentication

This error appears in the authentication process:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was doing some learning exercises a few days ago while creating a Facebook app and using Heroku as the host. My problem was that I had the wrong URL in my Facebook app settings for the "Website with Facebook Login" field value.

Also, for some hosts the URL may change depending on settings etc., so check your hosting URLs for the app and make sure you have the correct URL in that field on Facebook app settings.

Once I updated mine, the error went away and all is fine.

Good Luck!

Connie

Comment: Thanks alot for your valuable answers

Answer (score 0):

If you are on your development machine, be sure that you don't mix up localhost:3000 with 0.0.0.0:3000. Although on your development machine it is practically the same thing, the Facebook API won't recognise this and will return the error. Make sure the url is exactly the same everywhere.