# Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration while login using facebook Jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, facebook

I have to log in using Facebook credentials for my application,I am trying to do so by going through Facebook developer page documentation but I am getting error.

Error: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Further I have to package my jquery app for android.
I had added url for my site and mobile site: http://locahost
But still is is no working

Any suggestions would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098952/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration-facebook-application-e

Comment: @PatrickLC I solved the issue but I have a question I have to use this by packaging for android