# Login SSo facebook in angular

Tags: angularjs, facebook, single-sign-on

how to fix error

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: Can you share source code for SSO login via FB/Gmail in Angular?

Answer (score -1):

You have to add your application domain to allowed domains on Facebook App

Check this: [Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration Facebook application error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098952/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration-facebook-application-e)

Cheers