# "Given URL is not allowed by the Application Configuration" Facebook SDK Swift Error?

Tags: facebook, swift, sdk

I am creating a page where users can Login through Facebook. This error keeps popping up -- any idea how to fix this please?

Thanks!

[image: FB error message]

Comment: check...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098952/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration-facebook-application-e

Comment: Much better if you include the error message as text instead of an image...

Comment: The URL domain needs to match the one specified in the app dashboard. Follow the link provided by El Captain, it has the explanation. Or just use the Login Button https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#code-example